# How can I reduce the information my application requests

Tags: facebook

When users invite friends to my application the friend gets a notification in the Facebook.

When they click this link they see a dialogue box asking them to approve my application.

How can I limit the information my app requests to almost nothing so I don't scare away potential visitors.
 I don't want their email or friends list or to access their data at any time. I just want them to visit the site.

[image]

Ok Thanks to Changing the scope I have the dialogue down to this. Is there any way to get even less. I don't have any code that requires permissions. My call back just extracts the request id's.
[image]

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their great answers. I finally got it working without the dialogue box above.

Comment: bounty is still open, are you still looking for another solution? And are you using JS SDK for friend invites? some code would really help in providing a better solution. Because it is still not clear as to what you want to do. I understand that you want to remove the Auth dialog, but you might need auth for doing something else in your code. So put up some code, if you still need help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just don't require authentication on your landing page. Make it so that your landing page and primary canvas page do not require authentication and potential users can browse and check information about your app and look if it is what they are looking for.

Then once they make any significant action on your app when their user information is essential to proceed you can open an authentication dialog box. You can detect whether users already authenticated or not with the help of javascript API FB.getLoginStatus method:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I looked at my application on Facebook and I don't see where I can change the settings so Facebook does not require authentication. Where can I remove this?

Comment: It depends on implementation: if you are redirecting the user to OAuth Dialog, or call FB.login method in javascript SDK imeediately upon landing on your app - means - you require authentication. see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: I am doing neither.I redirect the user to just a landing page that checks the request ids but no authorization required.  I posted the image of what Facebook shows the user above to better explain my situation.

Comment: a link to the page and/or some code would help find the answer to your question.

Comment: @chell: this dialog means that you require authentication on landing. It is in your implementation and is not mandatory. It might be you 're trying to get access token or whatever (and this is not mandatory).

Comment: I finally found out what was going on thanks to your direction and now it works without a request for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You are requesting extended permissions in the url you are directing them to for the allow. Remove anything from the querystring parameter "scope", currently you should see that

`&scope=offline_access,email`

or similar. Simply change that to

```
&scope=
```

Check the page on extended permissions for more info:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

Your invitation is linked to application that needs extended permissions, you have two choice first one is change the link that don't needs extended permissions. Second one is if you don't use the data getting from permissions, remove the permissions from oauth dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The second screenshot above it the minimum amount of permissions you can request.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to request anything less than basic permissions. You have to have this in order for the user to be connected with your app, and so you can get their user id.